# How to enable code completion for custom modules in PyCharm?

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

When I import a module such as `numpy` by typing `import numpy as np`, and then start typing `np.`... Pycharm auto-completes the code and shows suggestions.

But when I import a custom module that I built (`import my_module as md`), typing `md.`... doesn't show up the inner attributes of the module (although completing the code manually works and runs successfully). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *mark*(*Mark Directory as*) folder with your package as *Sources Root*.

[image]

Steps:

*Right click* on folder -> **Mark Directory as** -> **Sources Root**

**UPD**: Also if folder does presented in project scope, open **Preferences** -> **Project** -> **Project Structure** -> **Add Content Root** -> And mark folder containing your module as **Sources**

Comment: I don't get it... Click on the folder where? Inside Pycharm in the project structure or something?

Comment: Yes. Open *Project structure* and click there.

Comment: @AlaaM. i've updated my answer for the case when you don't have desired folder in your Project view.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much (though I didn't see **Preferences**. I clicked **File > Settings** and searched for **Project Structure**)

Comment: @AlaaM. i meant PyCharm preferences (settings on Windows).

Comment: Yeah I didn't find a Preferences tab in Pycharm. I went to File > Settings